# IOS Storyboard when to use navigation controllers?

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

Hi I'm new IOS and have been using the storyboard feature, I followed [this](http://maybelost.com/2011/10/tutorial-storyboard-in-xcode-4-2-with-navigation-controller-and-tabbar-controller-part1/) tutorial which resulted in a working app. I'm slightly confused when to use a navigation controller. In the tutorial above, every tab had a navigation controller. Is this necessary?

I'm in the process of creating a new app and it seems to work whether I add a navigation controller or not to each tab (see pic).

[image: storyboard]

I'm just curios what is the correct process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As your app is using a `UITabBarController` each tab will display a separate 'branch' of views. If any of these 'branches' needs its views to be wrapped in navigation functionality (or simply display the navigation bar with a title etc) then you would add a 'UINavigationController` as the primary view controller for that tab, in between the tab bar controller and the first view controller you wish to display for that tab.

If you want a tab to simply display a view controller which doesn't need hierarchical navigation or a navigation bar then you wouldn't need to use a `UINavigationController` and can directly set your view controller as the controller for that tab.